# How to validate if the log started flowing after restart of a service?

Tags: scripting, logs, services

I have an use case where in part of validations one step is to verify whether the log file has started flowing after the service restart? How it can be achieved easily?

Comment: can you please expand on this ... currently it's not clear what you are even talking about

Comment: In my specific use case, there is a need to perform various validations, and one of these steps involves checking whether the log file has begun receiving new entries after restarting a particular service. This verification is crucial to ensure that the service is functioning correctly and that the log data is being recorded as expected.

Comment: What is the service environment? systemd? What about a oneshot-service that compares the service start time with the last modification time of the logfile?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are hoping for something more rigorous (and perhaps more amenable to automation) than "`tail -f` the log file in question and see if new messages keep appearing"?

If the service has a dedicated log file, and the service only opens the file when actually writing to it, checking that the file's last modification time is after the time you restarted the process may be the easiest way.

Something like:

```
starttime=$(date +%s)
# <insert command to start service here>
sleep 5   # wait for an appropriate time for service startup
filetime=$(stat -c %Y <insert logfile pathname here>)
if [ $filetime -gt $starttime ]
then
    echo "SUCCESS: service wrote at least one new log entry"
else
    echo "FAIL: no new log entries detected"
fi
```

If the log messages are in a format that includes a timestamp, you can also check that the timestamp of the last logged message is after the time of service restart.

However, the most thorough validation would be if you can make a request of a known type to the service, and thus provoke it into logging a message with contents you can anticipate. Then you can first check the log and note the file size/position, then send the test request, wait a suitable time, then search the log from the recorded position onward for the expected message.

Comment: Guess the timestamp one would be better option which is easy to do . does something like this work you think ?

but I am not sure how to put that in a program . 

I was thinking `time="date +%s"` gonna give , but irrespective of failure or success the the `time` will always have a vaule.